# Replace correlated subquery with CTE and JOIN

Tags: sql, join, common-table-expression

I am trying to rewrite a query which has a correlated subquery, the idea is to replace it with a **CTE** and **join** it later.

I have three tables, tbl_transaction, tbl_beneficiaries and tbl_reg_countries. The current (in short) SQL looks like the following.

```sql
SELECT
   t.USER_ID,
   t.TRANSACTION
FROM tbl_transactions t
JOIN tbl_beneficiaries b ON b.ID = t.USER_ID
WHERE b.COUNTRY NOT IN (
   SELECT rc.country
   FROM tbl_reg_countries rc
   WHERE rc.id = t.USER.ID)
```

My goal is to query only those transactions for each user where the transaction happens outside of the registered countries. So a user may registered X,Y,Z country but had business with Q. In that case only Q should be returned. How could this be replaced with a CTE/JOIN?

Comment: Is `tbl_beneficiaries.COUNTRY` a nullable column?

Comment: No, it will be always populated

Comment: `NOT IN` is a good choice for the case. Why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: Only for learning purposes, I wanted to seek other solutions (even if it is longer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume both `tbl_beneficiaries.COUNTRY` and `tbl_reg_countries.COUNTRY` are not nullable. You can use a `LEFT JOIN` with NULL test to detect never matching rows

```
SELECT
   t.USER_ID,
   t.TRANSACTION
FROM tbl_transactions t
JOIN tbl_beneficiaries b ON b.ID = t.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN tbl_reg_countries rc ON rc.id = t.USER_ID AND b.COUNTRY = rc.country
WHERE rc.country IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try rewriting query with "with"

Like this:

```
With a As
(Select 
    Distinct rc.country
From tbl_reg_countries rc
Inner Join tbl_transactions t on rc.id = t.USER.ID
)

Select 
   t.USER_ID,
   t.TRANSACTION
From tbl_transactions t
Inner Join tbl_beneficiaries b On b.ID = t.USER_ID
Where b.COUNTRY Not In (select * from a)
```